# How to create a user defined function in VBA that will replace the cell that calls the user defined function into another formula?

Tags: excel, vba

For instance I have a user defined function, but if I do `=Hours_alotted()` it will cause the cell to be populated with a string `"=min(8, [@[Hours Worked]])"` instead of replacing the formula in excel like the image shown below:

[image]

```
Function Hours_allotted()
    Hours_allotted = "=min(8, [@[Hours Worked]])"
End Function
```

Comment: A UDF can only be used to set the value, not the formula. If the function returns a formula like in your example, then you would have to use it within code (like the example below illustrates), not as a UDF.

Comment: I see that is unfortunate. I thought I could simplify my code by using a UDF. My problem is that I have to use events to actually activate the code which is troublesome because events often fire when cells are changed or worksheets are activated/deactivated (for my case) and sometimes the cells do not update or updates too often and is more error prone. I used to hard code all the conditions in the cell without VBA but would be a half page to 1 page long formula--which is too hard to look at and error prone due to too many nested loops

Comment: But then this method is also error prone now that I think about it since changes to the data will not be considered once the UDF can be replaced by a hard coded formula. I guess using events is the way to go to automate

Answer (score 0):

But why using a formula able to create a formula, and not the result of the formula. Of course, calculated in that VBA function...

Comment: I was hoping it had a visual effect for the user using the excel worksheet. But apparently it is not possible and makes it more error prone and less flexible. So I guess i'm sticking to this calculated in the VBA functions

Comment: It is not complicated to reproduce your worksheet function in VBA. Name it whatever you like. But it should return the result...

Answer (score -1):

You should add `.FormulaLocal` at the end of the cell assignment to read it as a formula in excel

`WorkSheet.Cells[1, 1].FormulaLocal = Hours_alloted()`

Comment: Thanks although I had automation in mind when asking the question. But as mentioned above it is not possible for a UDF to replace it into a formula